# XPages uploaded file: exception in embedObject

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have an XPages web app that allows users to upload files. An uploaded file is stored in a new Document's RichText field using the embedObject() function.  This has been working fine for quite awhile now, but recently someone tried to upload a file named "test.dir", and it causes an exception in embedObject.  Other typical file extensions we've tried work fine, and if we rename that same file to "test.txt" it works, but the ".dir" extension seems to cause a problem.  Does anyone know what the problem might be with ".dir"?  It's very strange!  TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Domino, `.dir` files are directory link files.  I expect that this is the source of the issue.

Full details and background:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/admn_creatingupdatinganddeletingdirectoryanddatabasel_t.html

You may be able to rename the file before embedding it as an attachment e.g. `test.dir.txt`

Comment: Thanks.  We figured it was something like that.  Too bad this limitation exists!

Comment: You might get around this limitation when you upload the file to a place that's outside the data directory tree, so Domino won't see it as part of its "virtual" file system. Haven't tried, but might be worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a complete different approach. `embedObject` requires that you store the file temporary in the file system before you can attach it.

When you process your document instead of RichText as MIME, you can create an attachment MIME part and directly stream the uploaded data into that part without storing it in a temp location first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  We have done it both ways, I think; not sure why in this case we're using the temporary file approach.